# How to Remove Categories Filter from the Sidebar

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, filter, sidebar

in Magento 2.1, I would like to have the Category filter removed from the sidebar when in the shop category page, leaving the price filter untouched.

So far I have tried unsetting the category as anchor, which doesn't change anything. I am able to remove the whole sidebar with XML, but that's not ideal because I want to keep using the price filter.

Comment: `Unsetting the category as anchor` should work, have you tried at the `store level` as well?

Answer (score 1):

**Override `view.phtml` file in your theme**

From

> vendor/magento/module-layered-navigation/view/frontend/templates/layer/view.phtml

To

> app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{theme}/Magento_LayeredNavigation/templates/layer/view.phtml

**Now set condition for category before `$filter->getItemsCount()`,**

```
<?php  

if($filter->getName() != __('Category')) {
    ...
    ...
} 

?>
```

**Final code looks like this**

```
...
...
<?php $wrapOptions = false; ?>
<?php foreach ($block->getFilters() as $filter): ?>
  ...
    <?php  if($filter->getName() != __('Category')) : ?>
        <?php if ($filter->getItemsCount()): ?>
            <dt role="heading" aria-level="3" class="filter-options-title"><?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__($filter->getName())) ?></dt>
            <dd class="filter-options-content"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getChildBlock('renderer')->render($filter); ?></dd>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
...
...
```

Comment: This unfortunately did not work for me.

Comment: @Martijnr face any issue?

Comment: This did not change anything. Any other suggestions Prince?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are referring cart page as shopping page.

In your theme, `checkout_cart_index.xml` add `<referenceBlock name="catalog.leftnav" remove="true" />` as follows

```
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="catalog.leftnav" remove="true" />
    </body>
</page>
```

Default Magento doesn't have layered navigation on cart page.

To remove it from every where you can use above in your theme `default.xml` or in `catalog_category_view_type_default.xml`

Comment: I edited my post, what I mean is the shop category page. When I use your XML code, it removes the complete sidebar including the price filter. I only want the category filter to be removed.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide subcategory filter from admin as  below

```
Store > configuration > catalog > catalog > Layered Navigation > Display Category Filter set to NO
```

[image]